# Increase max_execution_time in laravel

Tags: laravel

I need to increase max_execution_time in laravel app.

I made changes in `php.ini => max_execution_time = 180`

Also I add this line in `public/index.php` => `ini_set('max_execution_time', 180);`

Unfortunately, after 30 seconds I get 504 error. Is there any solution?

Comment: Have you restarted the server after changing the values ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen yes of course

Comment: Make sure that you're editing the right `php.ini` , in case your have multiple server, to make it confirm use `<?php phpinfo();` and see if it returns the same value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after changing in php.ini you have to restart your web server.

if you restarted it and nothing happened make sure you are changing in the right php.ini it is possible to have more than one in your operating system.

to avoid this you can make some changes in your `.htaccess` inside the public folder.

the change is:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value max_execution_time 300
</IfModule>
```

when you change in your .htaccess you dont have to restart your webserver.

> Note: you should have mod php5.c not commented

if you are insisting on making this change in the `php.ini` you can write `<?php phpinfo();` this will show you the location of your `php.ini` with all the information about the php version installed on your server